# What happens with named pipe when process on one side exits/crashes?

Tags: linux, redhat, named-pipes

I have two processes communicating via named pipes: one pipe transfers data from A to B and another one in the opposite direction.

What happens when one side exits/crashes without proper closing the pipe? Will the other side get `broken pipe` signal? How can the other side detect this situation?

It is RHEL 7.1